# datalist get selected value and custom attribute (without events)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html-datalist

I have a datalist with options and a custom attribute.

```
<input list="selectedItems" class="selectedItemsList"></input>
                                <datalist id="selectedItems">
                                    <option value="test11" oldvalue="f1"></option>
                                    <option value="test12" oldvalue="f2"></option>
                                </datalist>
```

It is displayed on a popup. When a popup closes the value and custom attribute value must be used in a function...

I tried:

```
alert($("#selectedItems option:selected").val());

alert($("#selectedItems option:selected").attr("oldvalue"));

$('.selectedItemsList option').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':selected')){
     alert($(this).val());
   }
});

for (var i=0; i<document.getElementById('selectedItemsList').options.length; i++)
                { 
                    if (document.getElementById('selectedItemsList').options[i].value ==  document.getElementsByName("selectedItems")[0].value) 
                    { 
                      alert(document.getElementById('selectedItemsList').options[i].value);
                      break;
                    }                                                
               }
```

Nothing works.

---

I can get the values using on-event but that is not an option for me.

```
$('.selectedItemsList').on('input', function() { ...  
alert($(this).val());
```

Comment: And what does the code for the popup look like, does it remove the markup from the DOM

Comment: Are you looking at this in safari?  Reason I ask is because datalists aren't supported in that browser

Comment: Here is my popup prototype: http://hallofhavoc.com/2013/05/how-to-create-an-overlay-popup-box-using-html-css-and-jquery/

I mainly use Yandex browser (=chromium)

`$('.overlay-bg, .close').click(function(){
            commitPopupChanges(false); /* here I get the datalist values */
            $('.overlay-bg, .overlay-content').fadeOut('fast');`

Comment: what is selectedDevices?

Comment: @gaurav5430
Thank you for pointing that out! selectedDevices is selectedItems. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){$("input[name=selectedItems]").on('input', function(){// selects which array raw is edited
            for (var i=0; i<dList.length; i++) if(dList[i].ItemName===$(this).val()) { num = i;
            $(".selectedItems option[value="+dList[num].ItemName+"]").val($(this).val());
            dList[num].ItemName=$(this).val();
        });
    });
```

So, I use datalist oninput event to get the selected value. Then, I edit a raw of an array of values that represents the datalist values.

```
var dList=[];num=0;
dList.push({ItemName: $(this).attr('value'), ViV: vs[0], NU: vs[1], ItemKey: $(this).attr('key')});
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, I believe the problem is related to your selector use.  I'm making the assumption that you're trying to get the old value from the datalist.  On closing your popup, you should get the value of the input first

```
var inputval= $(".selectedItemsList").val();
alert(inputval);
```

then grab the associated oldvalue based on the value of the input.

```
var oldval= $('datalist#selectedDevices option[value='+inputval+']').attr('oldvalue');
if (oldval)
    alert(oldval);
```

I created a jsfiddle for you here to play around with.
http://jsfiddle.net/jornjjt6/

Comment: Thank you! Why don't you use the class list name instead of datalist in "$('datalist option[v..."?

It does not work for me in my code. I dynamically add those list items like this:

`$("."+list).append('<li class="'+list+'Item" selectedFlag="0" value="'+item+'">'+item+'</li>');`
Does it change anything?

Comment: The datalist isn't a child of the input.selectedItemsList.  Although the input references the datalist to populate it's suggestions, the options aren't children of the input.  Due to this, you can't make calls like 
    $('.selectedItemsList option').each(...
This is why i set the value of the input to a variable and then looked up "oldvalue" after the fact.  datalists are merely suggestions, the user can still put in whatever they want so i additionally have to check is oldvalue is undefined.

Comment: Thank you! No. If I use the code inside an on-function.... but if I use the code to get the value inside other function that is not related to datalist event, nothing works, or gives me undefined value.
I have to get the chosen value. Then, when a user edits that selected value, I must pass both with ajax to servlet.

Comment: could you post your code via a jsfiddle?  i need to see what you're seeing to help

Comment: put my code in the very beginning commitPopupChanges and add an alert to inputval to see if you get any value at all from the input.  i'm wondering if one of your conditions is causing the issue.

Comment: I did. inputval shows up but not the oldval, it is undefined. Probably it takes the attr of the datalist, not selected option.
Since datalist's options are suggestions, attr 'selected' seems to be not set for options.

Comment: are you typing an option in or selecting it from the drop down?  if you are typing it and it's not exactly the same, it would be undefined because I'm not putting extra conditions in my if statement

Comment: First, I select an option. Then, I change its value. Then, I must pass itss old value and new value to servlet...
if statements may be removed for testing.